# How to send an std::vector<unsigned char> using asio::UDP socket.send_to

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, udp, boost-asio

I am trying to **synchronously send** an `std::vector<unsigned char>` through `boost::asio::ip::udp` from my server app to client app with following code like this:

```
boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
std::vector<unsigned char> buf_data;
std::size_t len = socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buf_data), remote_endpoint, 0, ignored_error);
```

This causes a hang & `socket.send_to` never returns.

However, *If I try to send a struct like below, it works nicely*

```
struct MyStruct
{
    char name[1024];
    int age;
};

boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
MyStruct send_data = {"something", 123 };
std::size_t len = socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(&send_data, sizeof(send_data)), remote_endpoint, 0, ignored_error);
```

*Also, If I try to send a std::string like below, it works as well.*

**What is different that I should do with call to `socket.send_to` when passing an `std::vector<unsigned char>` ? Does `socket.send_to` work with `std::vector<unsigned char>` or should use some other way to send the chars ?**

**PS:** The size of vector I am trying to send is `buf_data.size() is 140050`
&
I am on OSX

Comment: In your example, `buf_data` contains no data. Also why would you ignore the error_code? It's there for a reason.

Comment: Never used asio, but a vector is a non-POD class.  You want to send the data that the object represents, right?  So wouldn't that be `buf_data.data()`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Buffer has an overload for `std::vector` smart enough to pull both data and size.

Comment: I am populating `buf_data` properly. but populating the `buf_data` part of the code is not put into the question to keep it focussed to the point

Comment: @ChristopherPisz I will not ignore the error. just want to get past this send & receive issue firstly

Comment: _"This causes a hang & socket.send_to never returns."_ That [should not happen](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer/overload25.html). Please provide a SSCCE that reproduces the problem. /cc @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @sehe I have posted an extension of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891849/how-to-send-an-stdvector-of-unsigned-char-over-an-udp-socket-using-boost-asio) with proper compiling & running code to explain my problem. Please take a look if you could

Comment: Yup. SSCCE  provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891849/how-to-send-an-stdvector-of-unsigned-char-over-an-udp-socket-using-boost-asio)

Comment: Great. I hope you know see why SSCCE is essential: the question complete revolves around the false assumption that the sending side is the problem. It wasn't.

Comment: @sehe completely agree with the SSCCE point. I have also provided the compiler commands & the run command of how I am running the console apps I have

Comment: @sehe on the other point of yours, I might have mis-communicated that sending side is the problem but that wasn't my intention. Please do suggest in the extended question. the resize point you mentioned was important. I dont know why you deleted that answer, but the receive anyways wouldn't work without the resize. Hence I have added it in the code I have provided in the extended question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891849/how-to-send-an-stdvector-of-unsigned-char-over-an-udp-socket-using-boost-asio)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `buf_data.data()` did not help.

Comment: @AdaLovelace I deleted because you altered the question and there was just idle discussion about irrelevant things in the comment. Like I said, I would look at it later. But to me it looks like the resize fixes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143886/discussion-between-ada-lovelace-and-sehe).

Comment: @sehe your resize suggestion worked for me. pls repost you deleted answer on the extended question. I can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your buf_data contains at least one element, you can use the following:

```
boost::asio::buffer(&buf_data[0], buf_date.size())
```

as the first argument.

Comment: If `buf` is empty, the behavior is undefined.  Use `buf.data()` or have a check for `empty()` before using `&buf_data[0]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I specified that buf_data must contain at least one element.

Comment: I have the same problem with this solution. strangely just passing `boost::asio::buffer(buf_data)` with tcp works fine as well. but just doesn't seem to work with UDP which I badly need

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes. I am adding the empty check. `buf_data` is not empty. I confirmed this

Comment: @AdaLovelace Try using the same data structure but with small made up data.  If that works then the issue could possibly with your data size or content.

Comment: I have posted an extension to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891849/how-to-send-an-stdvector-of-unsigned-char-over-an-udp-socket-using-boost-asio) explaining the problem more vividly with the complete compiling code in the question itself. Please take a look